# Using docker-compose as a remote interpreter fails with a 'file not found' error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm, python-packaging

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this. I'm trying to set up a remote interpreter for debugging in Pycharm. I followed the instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html . The interpreter builds, but when Pycharm actually goes to lookup the packages, I get an error dialog saying

```
/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/opt/.pycharm_helpers/packaging_tool.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My first thought was that something was corrupted in Docker. I went into docker desktop, cleared out all the containers, images and volumes and tried again.The result was exactly the same.

When I look at the containers in docker I can see that I have two containers. One is the container for my app named 'simple' and the other is called 'pycharm_helpers'. pycharm_helpers has the packaging_tool.py file, buy it doesn't have the python executable (usr/bin/python3). simple has the python executable but is missing the packaging_tool.py file.

I'm pulling my hair out at this point. What is causing this issue and how do I fix it?